# VueJS 400 Bad Request on image source binding

Tags: encoding, escaping, vue.js

I have this VueJS site and im having issues loading some images. I receive a json response which i can loop over the properties no problem but when Im looping over the image src i get a 400 bad request for each image.

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)

http: //vue.dev/images/staff/%07Thompson_Jen.jpg

```
<div class="col-sm-4" v-for="employee in staff">

    <img :src="'/images/staff/'+employee.imageName">

</div>
```

if i navigate to the image through the dev tools it will try to load the above url but if try manually in the url without the %07, it works or if i hardcode the path it also works. Not sure why it is tacking on the %07.Does VueJS encode properties for attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be something in the JSON response that includes that BEL (%07) character.  VueJS is just adding whatever string it sees on the end there.  That character doesn't print so that would explain why you're not seeing it anywhere.

Comment: This was exactly the problem. The json response was adding it.XP